# YII Database Exception #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am facing trouble executing following Select Query in Yii framework.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS
>   `Invoiced_Amount` FROM `invoice` `i` LEFT JOIN `invoice_items` `ii` ON
>   i.invo' at line 1
>
> The SQL being executed was:

```
SELECT `i`.`invoice_id`, `i`.`Order_Type`,
`i`.`Trading_Partner_Name`, `i`.`Invoice_Create_Date`,
`i`.`Invoice_Status`, `ii`.`Item_Number`, `ii`.`Invoiced_Qty`,
`ii`.`Item_Rate`, Truncate((ii.Invoiced_Qty * ii.Item_Rate), `2)` AS
`Invoiced_Amount` FROM `invoice` `i` LEFT JOIN `invoice_items` `ii` ON
i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id WHERE `i`.`Invoice_Status`='17' LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Inconsistent back ticking is going to to bite you here. Note the problem in your TRUNCATE where you back tick before the 2 and after the closing parentheses  Truncate((ii.Invoiced_Qty * ii.Item_Rate), `2)`

Comment: The syntax should be more like `Truncate(ii.Invoiced_Qty * ii.Item_Rate, 2)`